# How to insert a variable in a multidimensional array inside a class

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, object, woocommerce

I'm editing a Woocommerce function to display different texts in different languages. I'm not familiar with objects, hence the call for help.

I need to insert a variable into a multidimensional array, but since it is an object, I have not been able to do it via array_push.

My goal is to insert the value of $comments_placeholder into the array key 'placeholder'.

Here's the current code:

```
    $this->fields = array(
        'billing'  => WC()->countries->get_address_fields(
            $billing_country,
            'billing_'
        ),
        'shipping' => WC()->countries->get_address_fields(
            $shipping_country,
            'shipping_'
        ),
        'account'  => array(),
        'order'    => array(
            'order_comments' => array(
                'type'        => 'textarea',
                'class'       => array( 'notes' ),
                'label'       => __( 'Order notes', 'woocommerce' ),
                'placeholder' => '',
        ),
    );

array_push($this["order"]["order_comments"]["placeholder"]) = $comments_placeholder;
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$this->fields['order']['order_comments']['placeholder']=$comments_placeholder
```

$this->fields refers to the array of the object, instead of $this, which refers to the object itself. Since 'placeholder' is a key and not an array, instead of array_push which appends a value to an array, you can assign the value of $comments_placeholder to the key 'placeholder' instead.

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked!. For the record, it also works if you put the $variable directly after the associative operator "=>". I somehow botched it before and didn't work the first time.